# How can I change tag brackets using RegEx?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to use RegEx to change `<` to `[` and `>` to `]`.

#### Example input:

```
<mailto:abc@xyz.com>
```

#### Example output:

```
[mailto:abc@xyz.com]
```

The email address obviously changes in each instance.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: How is this a regex?  Wouldn't this be a standard search and replace `<` with `[` and `>` with `]`?

Comment: actually this is '<mailto:abc@xyz.com>' unformatted text in html. html  create by client so not perfect so i want replace this text.
this type tag problem in create Html to pdf so i want regex for this.

Comment: @ManishSharma [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/N499J/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

If you're replacing all the `<mailto:`..`>` tags in an existing HTML doc then you're going to need something like:

regex:  `<(mailto:[^>]*)>`

replace with: `[$1]`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Regex

```
<([^>]+)>
```

#### Replacement

```
[$1]
```